# Asynchronous push of messages in channel (spring-integration)

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a simple JMS topic listener that i would like to hook with a spring-integration chain.
Basically, when a JMS message is received in the listener it has to be pushed into the chain's channel. Eventually the message is processed and pushed to an outbound-channel-adapter to be consumed.
The Spring Integration documentation mentions the use of asynchronous gateways but that uses Futures. 
Isn't there a simple way to just put the message on a channel?
If there is an example that you can point to it would be great.
Thanks
Regards
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the flow on the listener thread, simply use a regular gateway (not an async one); this will allow the message to roll-back if the flow fails for any reason.

If you want to "fire and forget" you can make the request channel from the gateway an `ExecutorChannel` - see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#executor-channel).

Comment: Thanks Gary for the prompt response!

Comment: Responding in the listener thread is OK for now at least. The gateway configuration takes an interface only. I would need to define my own implementation. How would i specify that? Thanks

Comment: You don't/can't - the framework generates the implementation (wraps the arguments into a `Message<?>` - see [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway)). If you want to perform further manipulation, you would add a `<service-activator/>` down stream.